# Find out CPU and memory usage percent of Docker container within its running environemt

Tags: docker, cpu-usage, memory-usage, containers, docker-machine

Does anyone know how to get resource consumption of a specific Docker container within its running environment?

Outside of a container, we can get it easily by typing a command "docker stats". Besides, if I try to get resource consumption inside a container, it will get the consumption (RAM, CPU) of the physical computer which the container runs on. Another option is using 'htop' command, but it does not show the result exactly compared to 'docker stats' command.